# cant read file from multipart\form data nginx+uwsgi+python3.9

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

Well, I'm struggling with this for days. I've tried so much options, but nothing can help me.
I need to read and process file, which client upload in form. But all that i've got is filename.
I've tried fieldstorage objects, werkzeug file wrappers, iobytes, webob and million of other options.
my configs:

```
[uwsgi]
module = test:application
chdir = /var/www/test.ru/python/
plugins = python3
virtualenv = /var/www/test.ru/python/myenv/
max-requests = 5000
processes = 5
threads = 2
master = true
#http = :8080
die-on-term = true
socket = wsgi.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
uid = braimage
gid = braimage
need-app = true
strict = true
limit-post = 52428800
```

nginx:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        #root /var/www/test.ru/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name here goes my external ip;
        charset utf-8;
        client_max_body_size 50M;

        location / {
                root /var/www/test.ru/html;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.py$ {
                root /var/www/test.ru/python;
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass unix://var/www/test.ru/python/wsgi.sock;
        }
}
```

html form:

```
<form action="test.py" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data>
            <label for="file">Загрузить заполненный шаблон:</label>
            <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" accept=".xls .xlsx">
            <button>обработать файл</button>
```

test.py:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request
import io
import cgi

def application(environ, start_response):
    #body_length = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', '0'))
    #request_body = environ['wsgi.input'].read(body_length)
    d = cgi.FieldStorage(environ=environ, fp=environ['wsgi.input'], keep_blank_values=True)
    #file_data = d['myFile'].file.read()
    #filename = d['myFile'].filename
    #df = pd.read_excel(file)
    htmlResponse = [ "<!DOCTYPE html>" ]
    htmlResponse.append("<html>")
    htmlResponse.append("<head>")
    htmlResponse.append('<meta charset="utf-8">')
    htmlResponse.append("</head>")
    htmlResponse.append("<body>")
    #for v in file.items():
    #    htmlResponse.append("<p>environ[] = {str(v)}</p>")
    htmlResponse.append(f"<p>Your value: <span style='color:blue;'>{str(d)}</span></p>")
    #htmlResponse.appendf("<p>Your value: <span style='color:blue;'>{filename}</span></p>")
    htmlResponse.append("</body>")
    htmlResponse.append("</html>")
    start_response("200", [("Content-Type", "text/html")])
    return[ line.encode("utf-8") for line in htmlResponse ]
```

for now script always returns something like:

```
Your value: FieldStorage(None, None, [MiniFieldStorage('myFile', 'file.txt')])
```

oh, and nginx shows errors like:

```
2022/10/23 16:18:14 [error] 4992#4992: *252 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: my client's ip, server: my server's ip, request: "POST /test.py HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix://var/www/test.ru/python/wsgi.sock:", host: "my server's ip", referrer: "my servers ip"
```

Answer (score 0):

error was typo in html form so
`enctype="multipart/form-data` (forgot tail ")

leads to transfer request as type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
thats why only thing I've got was filename.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).